# Как узнать pop\imap адрес почтового сервера для почтового ящика через whois?

Tags: pop3, email, imap

Добрый вечер.

Есть нетривиальная задача:

Как узнать pop\imap адрес почтового сервера для почтового ящика через whois?

Возможно ли такое?

p.s. Например, есть сервис для проверки существования email-ящика: http://domw.net/service:network-email

Но вот, как узнать адрес pop\imap сервера, для меня загадка.

Comment: > Но вот, как узнать адрес pop\imap сервера, для меня загадка.

В системе DNS существуют записи типа MX (Mail Exchange), которые тем или иным способом указывают на сервер(а), ответственный(е) за приемку писем. Соответственно вам нужен простой DNS-запрос mx-записей конкретного сервера. Дальше уже надо стучать по портам, чтобы узнать, какие сервисы включены (стандартный порт smtp, по которому реально бегает почта между серверами - 25, он не имеет отношения к pop и imap).

Comment: @Etki, тоесть алгоритм такой: 1) Получаем первую MX запись через whois 2) Стучимся по стандартным портам pop например на эту запись И все? Но вот вопрос - сможет ли почтовый клиент подключиться к этой записи. Если можно то чуть поподробнее.

Comment: @z668, похоже, что в общем случае (действуя по такому алгоритму) -- **никак**.

Да и в самом деле даже сервера (железки) для приема почты и ее выдачи пользователю м.б. разными.

--

Кстати, приведенный Вами сайт корректно существование e-mail не определяет...

Comment: @avp, понятно, спасибо. Насчет корректности определения - вы правы, допустим с яндексом такое не пройдет, да и не с им одним.